# List files with certain characters and output the file name plus other characters

Tags: batch-file, dos

I am trying to create a batch script to generate a xml file. The part I am struggling with is to list the names of the files(without extension) in directory that contain the text "@isTest" and add certain characters before the name. So for example in a directory with files

```
a.cls
b.cls
```

I want to obtain a xml file like this

```
<runTest>a</runTest>
<runTest>b</runTest>
```

I have managed to list the files but I don't know how to take the name, remove the extension and add the extra characters.

findstr /s /i /m "@isTest" *.cls >> file.xml

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use FOR /F to iterate the results of any command - one line per iteration. Type `HELP FOR` or `FOR /?` from a command prompt for more information.

You are using the recursive FINDSTR  `/S` option, so your output may include path information as well.

If you really only want the name, without path or extension, then the following will work:

```
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in (
  'findstr /s /i /m "@isTest" *.cls'
) do (echo ^<runTest^>%%~nF^</runTest^>) >>output.xml
```

The `~n` modifier preserves just the name of the value, discarding path and extension info. Note how I escaped the special characters `<` and `>` so they are not treated as redirection operators.

If you want to preserve path and name, and only strip the extension, then simply use `~dpn`:

```
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in (
  'findstr /s /i /m "@isTest" *.cls'
) do (echo ^<runTest^>%%~dpnF^</runTest^>) >>output.xml
```

The above will expand the relative path provided by FINDSTR into the full path.

If you want to preserve only the relative path, then you will need to do a substring operation instead of using FOR variable modifiers. I toggle delayed expansion on and off within the loop to preserve any `!` that may appear in your file names.

```
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in (
  'findstr /s /i /m "@isTest" *.cls'
) do (
  set "file=%%F"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  (echo ^<runTest^>!file:~0,-4!^</runTest^>)
  endlocal
) >>output.xml
```

Comment: wow great thanks so much! Great explanation. Just one final question if you dont mind.  I need to also search for the string "testmethod void", how can I make findstr to treat the that as a single search term instead of 2 different strings? I need @istest and testmethod void

Comment: @PepeFloyd - Read the FINDSTR help (type `help findstr` or `findstr /?`). You want the `/C` option: `/c:"testmethod void"`. You can specify multiple search strings (or logic) via multipe `/C` options.

Answer (score 0):

```
set noext=%file:~0,-4%
echo %noext% >> output.xml
```